# Selenium with firefox addons?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Just wondering, is there anyway to use selenium with firefox addons? I installed an addon but whenever i start the selenium driver it seems to kick off firefox without it. just curious

Comment: You can create a firefox profile & use this profile name to create a driver instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it simple like this

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension("/path/to/file.xpi")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: profile.add_extension("C:\Users\Mo\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\unu20kmj.default\extensions\uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi")
                         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.

Will attempt to solve

Comment: you need to escape "\" with "\\" or use `r"path\to\file.xpi"` and location for xpi file can be anywhere like `profile.add_extension(r"D:\file.xpi")`

Comment: no error message, but the addon doesn't appear to load. its alright don't worry about it. i will not be running this program often so that level of automation is not required.